# Find closest number greater than or equal to in Range

Tags: excel, vba

The function is working perfect for the two below conditions:

1. Find closest number in range
2. Find closest number less than or equal to in Range

For third condition when I call the function to `find the closest value above your target`, it returns `No value found` although there is value close to the value and greater to the target defined.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Output = TextBox1.Value
    MatchVlu = FindClosest(Range("I2:I32"), Output, 1)

    TextBox2 = MatchVlu
End Sub

Function FindClosest(ByVal rng As Range, Target As Variant, Optional Direction As Integer) As Variant
    'DESCRIPTION: Function returns the nearest value to a target
    'INPUT: Pass the function a range of cells, a target value that you want to find a number closest to
    ' and an optional direction variable described below.
    'OPTIONS: Set the optional variable Direction equal to 0 or blank to find the closest value
    ' Set equal to -1 to find the closest value below your target
    ' set equal to 1 to find the closest value above your target
    'OUTPUT: The output is the number in the range closest to your target value.
    ' Because the output is a variant, the address of the closest number can also be returned when
    ' calling this function from another VBA macro.
    t = 1.79769313486231E+308 'initialize
    FindClosest = "No value found"
    For Each r In rng
        If IsNumeric(r) Then
            u = Abs(r - Target)
            If Direction > 0 And r >= Target Then
                'only report if closer number is greater than the target
                If u < t Then
                    t = u
                    Set FindClosest = r
                End If
            ElseIf Direction < 0 And r <= Target Then
                'only report if closer number is less than the target
                If u < t Then
                    t = u
                    Set FindClosest = r
                End If
            ElseIf Direction = 0 Then
                If u < t Then
                    t = u
                    Set FindClosest = r
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: If you use minifs() manually, do you get the value expected?

Comment: You can do using an array formula too.  Data in A1:A19, value looking for is in B1.  Would be `$B$1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$19<B1,$B$1-($A$1:$A$19)))` for the closest value under.  Changing - and < to + and > would give the other way, like `$B$1+MIN(IF($A$1:$A$19>B1,($A$1:$A$19)-$B$1))`

Comment: Set a range of 3 cells: less, equal and greater than Target. This will make it trivial to troubleshoot, just set break points and use F8 to execute line by line.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```vb
Function FindClosest(ByVal rng As Range, Target As Variant, _
                     Optional Direction As Integer = 0) As Variant
    Dim t, r As Range, u, v, vl
    FindClosest = "No value found"
    For Each r In rng
        vl = r.Value
        'make sure numeric and not empty...
        If IsNumeric(vl) And Len(vl) > 0 Then
            u = r - Target
            v = Abs(u)
            If (Direction > 0 And u >= 0) Or _
               (Direction < 0 And u <= 0) Or _
                Direction = 0 Then
               
                If v < t Or IsEmpty(t) Then
                    t = v
                    Set FindClosest = r
                End If
            
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```